# Any idea why my carousel does not automatically change pics?

Tags: javascript, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to make a carousel on my website, so that it will automatically change four pictures around. Here is my code, however I am stuck in trying to figure out why it wont change any of the pictures:

```
                <div class="carousel">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#homeCarousel').carousel({
                    interval:3000,
                    pause: "false"
                });
            });
            </script>

            <!-- Carousel start -->
            <div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide">
              <!-- Menu -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Items -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">

                  <!-- Item 1 -->
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/l1.jpg">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                  <!-- Item 2 -->
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/l2.jpg"> 
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                  <!-- Item 3 -->
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/l3.jpg">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Carousel end -->
            </div>
```

I have tried doing changing the interval times, reformatting everything, checking out different post however I just cannot seem to figure it out.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: pause should be boolean false not string false.

Comment: That still does not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, the bootstrap carousel is heavily dependent on bootstrap CSS. You don't have it in your post, so make sure you have that reference in your page.

After that, your issue is in your `<li data-target="#myCarousel"...` lines. Those need to reference your carousel div, so they should have `data-target="#homeCarousel"`

Once I fixed that your code worked for me.